# How to use Select-Object, Where-Object to get correct value in hash table

Tags: powershell

I have the following hash table, $finalArray:

```
@{Name1=Yellow; Name2=Pallet Town; Name3=Ash; ID=12; Date=2019-07-01; DeviceID=1234} @{Name1=Blue; Name2=Pallet Town; Name3=Gary; ID=14; Date=2019-07-02; DeviceID=5678}
```

I'm attempting to get Name3 where the value of ID = 12, which should return Ash, but get the following error:

```
Select-Object $finalArray.Name3 | Where-Object $finalArray.ID -eq "12"
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
```

Anyone got any pointers/better way of evaluating the value?

Comment: Judging by the output format `$finalArray` is an _array_ of _custom objects_ (`[pscustomobject]` instances), not a hashtable (or array of hashtables).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you have array of hashtables (since your variable name means that), first you should define it as follows:

```
$finalarray = @( 
    @{
        Name1 = 'Yellow';
        Name2 = 'Pallet Town';
        Name3 = 'Ash';
        ID = 12;
        Date = '2019-07-01';
        DeviceID = 1234
    }, @{
        Name1 = 'Blue';
        Name2 = 'Pallet Town';
        Name3 = 'Gary';
        ID = 14;
        Date = '2019-07-02';
        DeviceID = 5678
    }
)
```

Now you want to get Name3 of the hashtable that's `ID = 12` as follows:

```
($finalarray | where ID -eq 12).Name3
```

**Note**

If you are defining the ID as string (i.e ID = "12") then you should use `Where ID -eq "12"` not `Where ID -eq 12`.

Comment: Nicely done; as an aside: the output format in the question implies that the array contains _custom objects_ (`[pscustomobject]`), not hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

No worries about this, I figured out I could use something like:

```
($finalArray | Where-object {$_.ID -like "*12*"}).Name
```